# j2me - Is it possible to read/write text files without having to use the FileConnection API?

Tags: java-me

I'm developing an application for taking orders.
Everything is OK with consuming webservices and that kind of stuff , the problem comes when I have to save all the read data into the device and then query that data.
At the moment I'm using RMS. I have two record stores (one for products and one for clients) but I'm not sure about the performance when I'll have to save a considerable number of records especially for the **products**.

I didn't even tried to write the results from the webservices into text files because [the book](http://www.amazon.es/Kicking-Butt-MIDP-MSA-Applications/dp/0321463420) I read before starting to develop my app stated that :

> Reading and writing files requires appropriate permissions, which
>   means you have to cryptographically sign your application to make sure
>   your users aren’t plagued by security prompts. As you read in Chapter
>   5, signing is expensive in terms of time and money. By contrast, your
>   application can use RMS for free.

But now that I've been through all the pain of having to use RMS to store objects (serilized using json) :

```
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(mRecordStoreName, true);
            byte[] raw = stringJSON.getBytes();
            idNuevoRegistro = rs.addRecord(raw, 0, raw.length);
```

I started to wonder if there wasn't any way to write text files , specially for data that I'm not going to update like **products** and **clients**.

The answer to my question might be a simple NO, but at least it's worth trying.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using FileConnection to write data and have no issues.
you state the permission in the Application Descriptor (JAD) file and use it.

if the app is not signed (which is indeed expensive but not so hard, just a bit of commandline magic), on more strict systems like symbian it will ask the user "can i open this file/can i write to this file" everytime it writes, and on less strict systems such as Sony Erricson it won't even ask.

Comment: This is the [model](http://developer.nokia.com/devices/device-specifications/nokia-208) I'm going to use.  I didn't want to use FileConnection because I can't sign the MIDlet(money reasons). I guess I'll have to stick with RMS then :(

Comment: @eddy , that model is symbian.It will display the annoying " Allow application to read/write data?" popup.I insist you use the RMS itself.

Comment: @CoolGuy I see :( but tell me, have you ever used RMS to store a considerable number of records, say 900 or 1000?? If so, did you experience performance problems??

Comment: @eddy ,I've am already making a j2me game in which i am making use RMS.but i've never stored 100 records in my recordstore.i dont know about performance problems ,but if your app/game hangs when reading data,you can set a simple loading screen and load the data in the meantime

Comment: RMS storage size varies a lot from device to device. I'd think newer devices have plenty of space available for RMS. But newer devices also gives users the choice of "Never ask again" for the security popup. So using the FileConnection API shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @mr_lou But I guess this [Nokia](http://developer.nokia.com/devices/device-specifications/nokia-208) is not among those newer models, is it?

Comment: Have to admit I've been using mostly Sony Ericsson models. But I'm fairly sure I've seen the option in a Nokia N8 as well.